# Cannot set bool property in QML item with calling C++ method

Tags: qml, qt5, qtquick2

I am trying to assign property in QML `Item` according to return value of C++ object method:

```
property bool ueAnyUserLoggedStatus: {
    ueApplicationStatus.ueAnyUserLogged()
    print(ueApplicationStatus.ueAnyUserLogged())
}
```

This chunk of code outputs the following debug info:

> qml: false qrc:/gui/items/UeKeypad.qml:14:42: Unable to assign
>   [undefined] to bool

The result of `ueApplicationStatus.ueAnyUserLogged()` is `false` and of type `bool`:

**Header declaration:**

```
Q_INVOKABLE bool ueAnyUserLogged() const;
```

**Implementation:**

```
bool UeApplicationStatus::ueAnyUserLogged() const
{
    return !this->ueUsers()->isEmpty();
}
```

Why is QML reporting

> qml: false qrc:/gui/items/UeKeypad.qml:14:42:  Unable to assign
>   [undefined] to bool

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this code you're not assigning the bool return to the property:

```
property bool ueAnyUserLoggedStatus: {
    ueApplicationStatus.ueAnyUserLogged()
    print(ueApplicationStatus.ueAnyUserLogged())
}
```

You are running the code between brackets and assigning the return of it to the property, what happens is that this code doesn't return anything, that's why you get an **undef**.
You think you're assigning the return of `ueApplicationStatus.ueAnyUserLogged();` to your property, but you are actually assigning the return of the `print` (the last statement).

To make it work as you expected you must have the `ueApplicationStatus.ueAnyUserLogged()` call as the last statement or you can assign the value to a variable first and then return it as the last statement (if you wanna call the `print`, for example).

Example code:

```
property bool ueAnyUserLoggedStatus: {
    var anyUserlogged = ueApplicationStatus.ueAnyUserLogged()
    print(anyUserlogged)
    return anyUserlogged
}
```